# How to plot various textures on geometry in Three.js

Tags: three.js

The map that I am attempting to create is isometric and is plotted in 44x44 pixel tiles. Each tile material is a loaded image.

Material with ID 1 might be reused at various x/y positions within the view. Material with ID 2 might only be used once. The same goes for any remaining tiles that need to be plotted.

I haven’t found anything in the docs that would be helpful and suggestions found on the web to use `createMultiMaterialObject` seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only a single geometry and want to apply multiple materials on it, you have to define so called [groups](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups) data. These data allow you to render different parts of the geometry with different materials. After defining groups, you can create your (multi-material) mesh like so:

```js
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [ material1, material2, material3 ] );
```

`three.js R111`